# setTimeout inside for loop with random values

Tags: javascript

Problem is that `setTimeout` function within `for loop` is not getting the correct values despite the fact they were passed correctly. Second problem is that the `sleep` variable is not working, it simply ignores it. Other variables like `i` are acting strange, they are not going though the loop, they are going in a random order.

Inside function `set_delay`

```
console.log(i); 
// 3,5,0,2,4,1 should be 0,1,2,3,4,5
console.log(sleep); 
// 6000,6000,7000,9000,9000,10000, those ones are displayied in ASC order but shuold be randomly
console.log(share_screen_rate[i]); 
//4,1,6,10,6,2,8 - this is not ok it's random
console.log(top); 
// 749.5,2998,299.8,499.667,149,374.75 =>  this should be in order from smallest (149) to biggest (2998)

setTimeout(function() {

}, sleep);
```

if I change `sleep` to a numeric value like `2000` it is respected only for first iteration after nothing, it just goes at 0ms.

FULL CODE

https://jsfiddle.net/ojpv2nxu/

EXPECTED OUTPUT

This should be a simple script to scroll down the page and make pause based on the `sleep` variable and also read the page chunk by chunk based on the `share_screen_rate` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a logic issue.... You are expecting the setTimeout to happen x seconds after the last one. But they are firing x seconds after you set it. So it is working as expected.

If you want them to fire x seconds after the last, than you need to change the logic to keep track of the seconds and adjust the timers.

so top of the file add

```
var timeTrack = 0
```

and than you need to add to that value

```
timeTrack += sleep
setTimeout(function() {

}, timeTrack);
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the ordering issue, have a look at the `console.log(sleep)` from function `scroll_page()` within the for loop, like that the sleep variable should be shown also in function `set_delay`. Also what about the other issue, the fact that i doesn't go like it should `for (var i = 0; i < share_screen_rate.length; i++) {` it goes randomly.

Comment: Your comment says inside the for loop it is in correct order. Than the comment inside of the setTimeout says they are in the wrong order..... `setTimeout(()=>{console.log(1);}, 2000); setTimeout(()=>{console.log(2);}, 1000);` is going to log `2` and then `1`..... You are saying it should be `1` and than `2`......

Comment: Yes, this is odd, inside the for loop is correct, but inside the set timeout not correct order.

Comment: Because the intervals run at different times....... 200 runs before 300. In your reasoning 300 will come before 200. setTimeout is not a queue. It says after XXX milliseconds, run this.

Comment: Ok, did not added the timetrack variable at top of file, is working fine. Thank you.